# Array of objects bug with index

Tags: php, arrays

I have a foreach like :

```
    foreach($values as $key => $value){
        $name = $value['name'];

        if(!isset($array[$value['position']])){
            $array[$value['position']] = new \stdClass();
        }

        $array[$value['position']]->$name = $value['value'];
    }
```

So in my loop, in `$value`, I have `$name`, `$position` and `$value`.

- $name is the name of the property
- $value is the value
- $position is the position of the object in the array (index)

In this loop, i check first in my object is already created in the specific index (position), if not i create it, and after i put the value in the correct property.

My problem is, if in my array of value i don't have all the positions following (0,1,2,3) but for example (0,1,3,4), my script bug and i don't have the correct array at the end.

How can i detect if i miss an index ? And how can i fix this ?

Thanks for help !

PS : I don't know if you have enough informations.. tell me !

**EDIT :**

At the end, the correct output must be :

```
[Object { name="d",  complet="false"}, Object { adresse="d",  complet="false"}]
```

But, if the script bug with the index, i have :

```
Object { 0={...},  1={...},  2={...},  plus...}
```

Comment: Please make a little example of what `$values` could hold, what the current output is and what the expected output is

Comment: $values is just an array with position, value and name

Comment: If I understand correctly, [array_values](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) could be used to index an array sequentially

Comment: I can't use array_value, this feature mix me all the array... @danronmoon